# find command with absolute paths if result is a file/dir

Tags: bash, path, find

I would like to alias the find command in linux to a function that will print the absolute path if the output of the find command is a file or directory on the file system?

Here's what I've got so far, but it doesn't work right.

```
find_with_abspath(){
    for i in $(find "$@")
    do
        if [ -e "$i" ];
        then
            readlink -m "$i"
        else
            echo -n "$i"
        fi
    done
}
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: It works on my system, except for file- and directory-names that contain spaces (since `for i in $(find "$@")` splits by spaces, tabs, and newlines -- all of which are legal in filenames, but tabs and newlines are admittedly quite rare). What are you finding that "doesn't work right" about it?

Comment: I'm not convinced `readlink` does what you expect.  At least on the MacOS X and Linux systems I have, it errors if the file name given is not a symbolic link.  I suspect that what you'd like is a similar program that provide the output from the `realpath()` function or system call.

Answer (score 2):

```
## define your function
abspath() {
    while read -r; do
        [[ -d $REPLY || -f $REPLY ]] && readlink -m "$REPLY"
    done
}

## run as:
$ find foo -iname "*.png" | abspath

## or:
$ abspath < <(find .. -.. ..)
```

you don't need to redefine `find` in your function. Your function can be used to just get input, and print the absolute path.

Answer (score 2):

Adaption of siegex answer above that works with ZSH:

```
# usage: afind . -name \*.html
afind() { baseDir=$(readlink -f $1); shift; command find $baseDir "$@" }
```

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to turn the path given to `find` into an absolute path before the command is invoked.  This following bash 1-liner does exactly this by intercepting the `find` command, manipulating the path and then calling the real `find` command.

```
find(){ ( set -f; command find $(readlink -f $1) ${@:2}; ) };
```